# Current page slug being added to links, menu and asset urls Typo3

Tags: php, url, typo3

I'm moving a Typo3 version 4.5 site from one host to another. The hosting environment is very similar and all apache essentials are active.

The Typo backend works with no issues and the front end loads as expected, *but*, only when connected to the current page directly. Once you start to navigate the site from that page, it's page slug get's added to all links, menu and asset urls.

The htaccess and config files have not been changed from the setup on the previous host and the base url are set automatically, as in, not set explicitly in ay files or in the database.

All caches have been cleared as well as the tempconf folders contents.

The site uses the following extensions concerning URL's:

- RealURL Management" 0.3.4
- RealURL: speaking paths for TYPO3

Here's an exmaple of what I'm seeing.

1. Go directly to www.website.com/home
2. Click on the menu item "about"
3. I'm taken to www.website.com/home/about
4. All urls on the page now have "/home/" in them

But if you go directly to www.website.com/about all urls are generated correctly so it's only by clicking through to another page on the site that the incorrect url is generated.

After some time working with this I've not been able to resolve the issue. Any suggestions as to why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like TYPO3 archeology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like missing `config.baseURL` or `config.absRefPrefix` (preferred one). Did you look into the documentation of RealUrl?

Comment: I did, but the documentation, comments and config for Typo have been quite alien to me so far (more likely my approach than the system). I had set the base url and that didn't work - for some reason it wasn't clear to me to that it was okay to use the absrefprefix - I did and it worked, thank you very much.